# Извлечение файлов из архива

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Есть класс который извлекает файлы из архива с перезаписью:

```
public static class ZipArchiveExtension
{

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive archive, string destinationDirectoryName)
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
        {
            string completeFileName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, file.FullName);
            if (file.Name == "")
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName));
                continue;
            }
            file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
        }
    }

}
```

Вот я его вызываю:

```
ZipPath = textBox4.Text + textBox5.Text + ".zip";
ExtractPath = textBox4.Text;
ZipToOpen = new FileStream(ZipPath, FileMode.Open);
Archive = new ZipArchive(ZipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true, Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866"));
ZipArchiveExtension.ExtractToDirectory(Archive, ExtractPath);
```

Мне нужно что-бы при вызове метода я ещё указывал строковый массив с именами файлов которые не надо перезаписывать.
Допустим я добавлю во входящие параметры метода строковый массив и заведу строковый массив с именами файлов которые не надо перезаписывать.

```
public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive archive, string destinationDirectoryName, string[] Massive)

string[] Massive = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"};
```

Что делать дальше? Сравнивать в цикле массив с file.Name в foreach с помощью if, выполняя код если имена не совпали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сравнивать в цикле массив с file.Name в foreach с помощью if, выполняя код если имена не совпали?

Это вариант. В качестве альтернативы можно вместо цикла использовать [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
{
    //пропущено тело цикла
    //ignoredFilenames - массив игнорируемых файлов
    bool overwrite = !ignoredFilenames.Contains(file.Name);
    file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, overwrite);
```

Если массив более нигде не используется будет логично сделать из него [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

```
var ignoredFilenamesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(ignoredFilenames));

//затем в цикле
bool overwrite = !ignoredFilenamesSet.Contains(file.Name);
```

можно также принимать [ISet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) в качестве аргумента.

Если игнорируемые файл вообще не нужно извлекать, то можно пропускать итерацию для файла:

```
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
{
    if(ignoredFilenamesSet.Contains(file.Name) continue;
    //... если не игнорируется, извлекаем
```